# Change btn color back to original when dropdown menu is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once a user clicks atleast 1 option from my dropdown menu, then the button colours change. Now when the user deselects ALL options (so that there are zero selected options), then I want the button colours to automatically change back to their original colours. Is that possible to achieve?
I tried working with if-else, but it didnt work. P.S. the user can deselect either unchecking each option box or use the "clear" button which clears all.

```
var i = $("li").index( $(this).parent() );

  if ( i === 1 ) {
    $('btn_clear').css('background', 'blue');
  } else if ( i === 2 ) {
```

Here is my BOOTPLY ... [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/nAupRgzzAp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your 2 click handlers to the 1 below:-

```
$(".products .checkbox, .availability .checkbox").on("click", function(e) {

  var menu = $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu');

  var checkCount = menu.find(':checked').length;

  $('.btn_clear', menu).css('background', checkCount > 0 ? 'blue' : 'grey');
  $('.btn_apply', menu).css('background', checkCount > 0 ? 'green' : 'yellow');

});
```

this just counts the `checked` from in its dropdown and sets the color accordingly.

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/twtbcWMtq3)

**addendum**

Here's the updated code for clear handler.

```
$(".btn_clear").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var menu = $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu');
    menu.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('.btn_apply', menu).css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: thanks, this would work for me, only when I click the "clear" button (to remove ALL checks), then the colours do NOT change back to originals. Can that be made possible too?

Comment: Try the bootly link again and look at the clear handler.

Comment: @raulbaros Inside "btn_clear" handler implement the same above code. What you can do is keep the logic inside a function and call them in both click events (clear button and checkbox)

Comment: @BG101 - brilliant, thanks a lot! vendettamit - thank you also!

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a default value for your color, and assign it that way:

```
var i = $('li').index($(this).parent()),
    // here is the "original" color of the button.
    color = 'red';

if (i === 1) {
    color = 'blue';
} else if (i === 2) {
    color = 'green';
} // etc

// Save yourself a bunch of repeated code, and only have the assignment once.
$('#btn_clear').css('background', color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using jQuery's [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) then defining what color that class should have. This allows for some separation of concern when dealing with application logic vs. styling

#### style

```
.blue-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
var i = $("li").index( $(this).parent() );

if ( i === 1 ) {
  $('btn_clear').addClass('blue-text');
} else if ( i === 2 ) {
  $('btn_clear').removeClass('blue-text');
}
```

Comment: This should have been a comment. It's not an answer.